# How to understand “有理数贯逼近实数”？

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [this article](http://www.kepu.net.cn/gb/hlg100/page_1028.htm), the phrase “有理数贯逼近实数” is used (see the second last paragraph). How to understand this phrase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"有理数" = rational numbers
"数贯" = (numerical) sequence (obsolete, the more conventional term nowadays is "数列")
"逼近" = literally, "to approach", "to get close to"； mathematically, "to approximate"
"实数" = real numbers

Therefore, "有理数贯逼近实数" means "using a sequence of rationals to approximate (a) real", so this sounds like something similar to a Cauchy sequence.

In context of this article, it is probably that Hua Loo-Keng was giving a lecture on the construction of real numbers using Cauchy sequences (likely in a real analysis course), and he introduced continued fractions (连分数) in the context of that.

**Disclaimer**: I am a native Chinese (Mandarin) speaker with a reasonable amount of knowledge of mathematics (but I am not a professional mathematician).

Answer (score 2):

Not a math guy, but this is what I found.

---

- 有理数 = rational number
- 贯 = sequence
- 逼近 = approximation
- 实数 = real number

---

- rational number sequence approximation of a real number

-or- perhaps more colloquially:

- the approximation of real numbers by rational number sequences

Comment: 逼近 is, apparently, not a noun word in this context.

Comment: 逼近 is defined by Grand Ricci as `(Math.) Approximation. `

Comment: It could be either "approximate" or "approximation", depending on  how you use it.

Comment: 贯 looks strange to me in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It should be understood in this way: 例如/在讲到/用"有理数贯"/逼近"实数"时

where 有理数贯 and 实数 are independent terms.

Answer (score 0):

- “[有理数](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%89%E7%90%86%E6%95%B0)": *可以表达为两个整数比的数 被定义为有理数 (A number that can be expressed as two integer ratios is defined as a **rational number**)*
- 数贯 = suite; sequence (math)
- 有理数贯 = 有理数数贯 (rational number suite/ sequence)

*As I see it, 数贯 is another name for 数学公式 (Mathematical formula)*

- 逼近 = approach/ close to
- 实数 = real number

> “有理数贯逼近实数” means "rational number suite close to a real number"

*I think a Mathematician can answer this better. I have no idea what is the difference between rational number and real number and what it meant when he said one is getting close to the other.*

Comment: 实数 should be real number

Comment: that show how little I know math. 'real ' and 'actual ' seem like the same to me at first, now I see 'actual number' could mean 'exact number'